# Incompatible types: A and kotlin.reflect.KType

Tags: kotlin

I want to check that function has parameter of `A` type use the following code:

```
import kotlin.reflect.*
import javafx.event.ActionEvent

interface IA {}

class A {}

class B {
    fun test(a: A, ia: IA, event: ActionEvent) {
        println(a)
        println(ia)
        println(event)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (function in B::class.declaredMemberFunctions) {
        for (parameter in function.parameters) {
            when (parameter.type) {
                is IA -> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
                is ActionEvent -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
                is A -> println("Has A class parameter.") // <---- compilation error in this line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to compile it I see the following error:

```
> Error:(20, 19) Incompatible types: A and kotlin.reflect.KType
```

Questions:

1. Why compiler don't raise error for `IA` interface and `ActionEvent` Java class?
2. Why compiller raise error for `A` class?
3. How to check that function has argument of `A` type?

Comment: Your accepted answer is only correct when not using generics.  You are comparing a `Type` to a `Class` which works only when the parameter does not have any generic types in it.

Comment: I added a more lengthy answer, sorry the topic is not that simple when generics are introduced.

Comment: do you need to check types that might specifically contain generics?  For example knowing if a parameter is `List<String>` versus `List<Cat>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is you're trying to check if `KType` is `A`, which is always `false`. And the compiler knows it and raises a compilation error. But `IA` is an interface a class that implements `KType` can possibly implement this interface too so there's no compilation error. `ActionEvent` is an open class so it's subtype can implement `KType` - no compilation error either.

What you should do to check if the parameter type is some class or some interface is the following.

```
when (parameter.type.javaType) {
    IA::class.javaClass -> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
    ActionEvent::class.javaClass -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
    A::class.javaClass -> println("Has A class parameter.")
}
```

Comment: Try to test your solution with my snippet. It should print 3 lines ("Has IA interface parameter.", etc.) but it doesn't print them. Could you please explain this?

Comment: I found out that you can't just compare `KType` with `KClass`. But you can get corresponding Java types and compare them. Please check the updated code.

Comment: A `Class` in Java is an instance of `Type` which is why that works in Java when both are really a `Class`, this is not the case in Kotlin.  But sometimes a `Type` might be something else, so this comparison won't always work as you think it would.  For example a `ParameterizedType` and `Class` won't compare equal.  So your code could fail if that type is one of the other 4 or 5 implementations of `Type`

Comment: The question is not about comparing parameterized types, isn't it? The author doesn't ask how to compare a raw type to a class.

Comment: But you @michael are comparing a java `Type` to a java `Class` in your answer.  And that isn't always correct when his use case MIGHT LATER include generics (I'm guessing he simplified it for here).  Nor does this answer handle inheritance which the attempted `is` check would have done.

Comment: I do. And yes, I know about all these problems. But again, the question is not about that.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are using the wrong operator.  `is` checks if an *instance* of something is a given class.  You have no instance.  You instead have a `KType` that you are trying to check if it is the instance of a class `A`, or `IA` or `ActionEvent`, it isn't.

So you need to use a different operator, which is to check if they are equal or call the method `isAssignableFrom()`.  And then you need to check that the two things you are comparing are the right datatypes and do what you expect.

In another answer, @Michael says you can just treat a `Type` and `Class` the same for equality, that isn't always true; not that simple.  Sometimes a `Type` is a `Class` but sometimes it is a `ParameterizedType`, `GenericArrayType`, `TypeVariable`, or `WildcardType` which are not comparable with equals.  So that approach is wrong if you ever have a parameter to the method that uses generics it breaks.

Here is a version that does not support generics in that if generics are used in  the parameter, they will not match.  This also compares `KType`using equality, which means it does not work for inherited classes matching against a superclass or interface.  But the most simple is:

```
 when (parameter.type) {
    IA::class.defaultType -> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
    ActionEvent::class.defaultType -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
    A::class.defaultType -> println("Has A class parameter.") 
 }
```

This breaks if For example if class `A` had generic parameter `T` so you wanted to check a parameter that is `A<String>` or `A<Monkey>` you will not match `A::class.defaultType` (FALSE!!!).  Or if you tried to compare array types, again will not match.

To fix this generics problem, we need to also erase the `paramter.type` you are checking.  We need a helper function to do that.

Here is one copied from the [Klutter library](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter) that takes a `KType` and erases the generics to make a `KClass`.  You will need the `kotlin-reflect` dependency to use this code.  *You can remove the `kotlin-refect` dependency by only working with Java `Class` and not using `KClass` anywhere directly.  Some other code will have to change.*

With the following extension function:

```
fun KType.erasedType(): KClass<*> {
     return this.javaType.erasedType().kotlin
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun Type.erasedType(): Class<*> {
    return when (this) {
        is Class<*> -> this as Class<Any>
        is ParameterizedType -> this.getRawType().erasedType()
        is GenericArrayType -> {
            // getting the array type is a bit trickier
            val elementType = this.getGenericComponentType().erasedType()
            val testArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(elementType, 0)
            testArray.javaClass
        }
        is TypeVariable<*> -> {
            // not sure yet
            throw IllegalStateException("Not sure what to do here yet")
        }
        is WildcardType -> {
            this.getUpperBounds()[0].erasedType()
        }
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Should not get here.")
    }
}
```

You can now write your code more simply as:

```
 when (parameter.type.erasedType()) {
    IA::class-> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
    ActionEvent::class -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
    A::class -> println("Has A class parameter.") 
 }
```

So generics are ignored and this works comparing the raw erased class against each other; but again without inheritance.

To support inheritance you can use this version slightly modified. You need a different form of `when` expression and a helper function:

```
fun assignCheck(ancestor: KClass<*>, checkType: KType): Boolean =
    ancestor.java.isAssignableFrom(checkType.javaType.erasedType())
```

Then the `when` expression changed to:

```
when {
    assignCheck(IA::class, parameter.type) -> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
    assignCheck(ActionEvent::class, parameter.type) -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
    assignCheck(A::class, parameter.type) -> println("Has A class parameter.")
}
```

#### Extra credit, comparing full generics:

To compare full generics we need to convert everything to something that we can compare that still has generics.  The easiest is to get everything into a Java `Type` since it is harder to get everything into a `KType`.  First we need a `TypeReference` type class, we'll steal this from [Klutter library](https://github.com/kohesive/klutter) as well:

```
abstract class TypeReference<T> protected constructor() {
    val type: Type by lazy {
        javaClass.getGenericSuperclass().let { superClass ->
            if (superClass is Class<*>) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information")
            }
            (superClass as ParameterizedType).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Now a quick extension method to use this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> ft(): Type = object:TypeReference<T>(){}.type
```

And then our `when` expression can be more detailed with generics:

```
for (parameter in function.parameters) {
    when (parameter.type.javaType) {
        ft<IA>() -> println("Has IA interface parameter.")
        ft<ActionEvent>() -> println("Has ActionEvent class parameter.")
        ft<A<String>>()  -> println("Has A<String> class parameter.") // <---- compilation error in this line
        ft<A<Monkey>>()  -> println("Has A<Monkey> class parameter.") // <---- compilation error in this line
    }
}
```

But in doing this, we broke inheritance checking again.  And we don't really check covariance of the generics (they themselves could have superclass checks).

#### Double Extra Credit, what about inheritance AND generics?!?

Um, this isn't so much fun.  I'll have to think about that one a bit, maybe add it to Klutter later.  It is kinda complicated.